# How to send client machine images to server DB?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, image-uploading

In simple words, Client will give image `PATH` in my `textarea` all those images should be saved in my server DB. Please give some code or idea to achieve this.

**Note:** Client may put more than one image `URL` in the `textbox`. I want to send all the images to the server.

Comment: What 'client' are you referring to? A web browser? A Java application?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials and examples. You need to divide your question into two questions, first upload file from browser to server second one is how to store an image in database. Here is an example to upload to a server http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/glraq.html

Comment: @Jason thanks for your fast replies. I'm referring to a web browser.

Comment: @Rp i'm not going to use file upload input type. It will be a simple textarea from where i will take the URL and send it to server. I have done the storing an image in Database.

Comment: If you just send a path to the server.. server wont have any clue about the client's file system. Here is a tutorial which explains mutli file upload http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: can I convert all the images to binary values like `FileReader` or `FileInputStream` and send it to my server? is it feasible and is that a good coding practice?

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us ,which clint are you useing.And if there is any framwork,like struts or others.